# How to implement truncate and load in target in informatica?

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

I want to create one to one mapping with truncate and load so how to implement this mapping?. Please tell me steps for this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your target type is (DB table, file, etc.) but basically you tick the "Truncate target" option on your target definition.